# getting key error for accessing the graph's weights, networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using networkx to create an algorithm to calculate the modularity for the different communities. Now I am getting this key problem when I was doing G[complst[i]][complst[j]]['weight'], whereas I printed out complst[i] and compost[j] and find these values are correct. Anyone can help? I tried many ways to debug it such as saving them in seperate variables but they don't help.

```
import networkx as nx
import copy
#load the graph made in previous task
G = nx.read_gexf("graph.gexf")
#set a global max modualrity value
maxmod = 0
#deep copy of the coriginal graph, since when removing edges, the graph will change
ori = copy.deepcopy(G)
#create an array for saving the edges to remove
arr = []
#see if all edges are broken, if not, keep looping, otherwise stop
while(G.number_of_edges()!=0):
    #find the edge_betweeness for each edge
    betweeness = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G,weight='weight',normalized=False)
    print('------------------******************--------------------')
    #sort the result in descending order and save all edges with the maximum betweenness to 'arr'
    sortbet = {k: v for k, v in sorted(betweeness.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}
    #covert the dict to list for processing
    betlst = list(sortbet)
    for i in range(len(betlst)):
        if betlst[i] == betlst[0]:
            arr.append(betlst[i])
    #remove all edges with maximum betweeness from the graph
    G.remove_edges_from(arr)

    #find the leftover component, and convert the result to list for further modualrity processing
    lst = list(nx.connected_components(G))
    #!!!!!!!!testing and debugging the value, now the value is printed correctly
    print(G['pk_sullivan']['ChrisWarcraft']['weight'])

    #create a variable cnt to represent modularity in this graph
    cnt = 0
    #iterate the lst, which is each component(each component is saved as python set)
    for n in range(len(lst)):
        #convert each component from set to list for processing
        complst = list(lst[n])
        #if this component is a singleton, the modualrity for this component 0, so add 0 the current cnt
        if len(complst)==1:
            cnt += 0
        else:

            # calulate the modularity for this component by using combinations of edges
            for i in range(0,len(complst)):
                if i+1 <=len(complst)-1:
                    for j in range(i+1,len(complst)):
                        #!!!!!!!!! there is a bunch of my testing and find the value are printed all fine until "print(G[a][b]['weight'])""
                        print(i)
                        print(j)
                        print(complst)
                        a = complst[i]
                        print(type(a))
                        b = complst[j]
                        print(type(b))
                        print(G[a][b]['weight'])
                        #calculate the modualrity by using equation M = 1/2m*(weight(a,b)-degree(a)*degree(b)/2m)
                        cnt += 1/(2*ori.number_of_edges())*(G[a][b]['weight']-ori.degree(a)*ori.degree(b)/(2*ori.number_of_edges()))
                        #find the maximum modualrity and save this split of graph, end!
                        if cnt>=maxmod:
                            maxmod = cnt
                            newgraph = copy.deepcopy(G)
    print('maxmod is',maxmod)
```

here is the error, welcome to run the code and hope my code illustration can help!
[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be giving any feedback to any answers, neither upvoting or accepting... Please let answerers know that they have helped you, as well as future visitors by giving some sort of feedback. This community is not just about getting your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to find the weight of all combinations of nodes within each connected component. But the problem, is that you're assuming that all nodes in a connected component are first degree connected, i.e. are connected through a single edge, which is wrong.

In your code, you have:

```
...
for i in range(0,len(complst)):
    if i+1 <=len(complst)-1:
        for j in range(i+1,len(complst)):
...
```

And then you try to find the weight of the edge that connects these two nodes. *But every edge in a connected component is not connected to the rest*. A connected component just means that all nodes are *reachable* from all others.

So you should be iterating over the edges in the subgraph generated by the connected component, or something along these lines.